# Backing up old Win7 as VHD and booting it in VMware - failed

Tags: windows, windows-7, boot, vmware, vhd

I tried backing up my old PC's hard drive using the Win7 System Backup.
I have now a 250gb .vhd file as a result, and I'm trying to boot it in VMware but I fail as the error "Missing Operating System" comes, even after choosing the correct boot order and so on.
UEFI won't work as this is a legacy machine.
The port is a SATA one and it is also configured that way in the VM.
In VirtualBox I get the same error but in a different form (INT18).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Isaac.

Comment: Try Vcenter converter to see if if can create a working VMDK file that works   .....    https://docs.vmware.com/en/vCenter-Converter-Standalone/6.2/rn/conv_sa_62_rel_notes.html

Comment: What do you want to do is essentially equivalent to moving your disk with installed Windows from one machine to another, with different hardware, and trying to boot it on that other machine. While this often can be done with Linux installation (although sometimes will require tweaking of some system files), this is usually impossible with Windows. I guess you'll have to install Windows from scratch in the VM, attach your .vhd file as a second disk to the VM (this should work) and copy data that you need from that second disk to the main one.

Comment: I could convert it to a VMDK file but it didn't help with the boot process.
Installing Win7 from scratch on the VM and then use the system recovery from the .vhd was my second idea.

Comment: Start all over.  Go back to the windows 7 machine and run [sysprep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation?view=windows-11) to generalize the machine before backing it up.  Keep your ORIGINAL backup (that didn't work) in case you don't like what sysprep did to you.  If it still fails, you probably aren't backing up the drive that has the bootloader on it.

Comment: so after trying the conversion with vCenter I get this error: FAILED: Unable to find the system volume, reconfiguration is not possible.
I would assume that's because I created a virtual machine which has this hard drive but it's not configured as a system drive.

Comment: Resolved with installing a new windows 7 machine and restoring up from an old image